# Creating 2D array from 1D array - Python Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Assuming I have a numpy array such as

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

How do I create a 2D matrix from each 3 elements, like so:

```
[
[0,1,2],
[1,2,3],
[2,3,4],
[3,4,5]
]
```

Is there a more efficient way than using a `for` loop?

---

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use a [sliding window view](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(6)
view = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(arr, 3)
```

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

Keep in mind however that this is a view of the original array, not a new array.

Answer (score 1):

Since OP does not want to use a for loop we can use libraries:

You can use `more-itertools` library:

```
#pip install more-itertools    # note there is a hyphen not an underscore in installation.

l=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
import more_itertools
list(more_itertools.windowed(l,n=3, step=1))

#output
[(0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5)]
```

or for lists of lists

```
list(map(list,more_itertools.windowed(l,n=3, step=1)))
[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Can also do with :

```
#pip install cytoolz
from cytoolz import sliding_window
list(sliding_window(3, l))
#[(0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5)]
```